# REST API and authentication or not?

Tags: angular, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, restful-authentication

I'm asking questions about developping application from scratch and I have some troubles : 
I'll have a front-end part (Angular) and a backend, they will classically communicate throught REST API on backend.
And for the context : this application (front + back) will be deploy on each equipment which want to use application, so there is no public global server API.

The question is : do I need in this context to authenticate requests made to backend ? 
Or do I have to consider that being local webservices no authentication is required ? And if I have to, knowing that Rest application must be stateless, should I use OAuth(with a little state part) + JWT excluding HTTP Session authentication ?

Thank you so much, there is some concepts I do not understand.

Edit : globally, the question is when to develop a simple REST application and when to develop authentication part for security ?

Comment: I think being auth, if there is data to secure or personnal data, is a requirement. + It allow to log and to know who is requesting. You can not just say "no one will know it exist".  If you have to secure it, do a auth else assume it is public (attackers can be in your internal network without you to notice)

I think JWT is mostly enough, OAUTH 2.0 is complicated to setup, jwt is straight forward, is fully stateless and is secure

Comment: What is the difference, in practice I noticed OAuth2 (for a specific grant at least) was using tokens ?

Comment: If I remember correctly the use is very different. Normal workflow of Oauth:

At the first connection of your user: you request an authorization at the third party service, the third party service give you an "Authorization Grant" (this is what you store for your user), then you can ask for a token (by nature the token has a limited duration). This is very interessant for third party service which should be used by an unknown service (facebook do not know who you are but it know what you are allowed to do)

Comment: So It allow the third party service to know what the user allowed you to access (stored in the "Authorization Grant" which is not limited in duration and is readable by you) without knowing who you are.
The JWT is just a token tactic, it allow you to communicate with a signed ( or encrypted) token: Let imagine you have a backend for user and a backend for order: The user is authenticated on the user's backend, the user backend send you back a JWT, then the order backend can assume you are the user stored in the JWT and then it allow you to know order for the user stored in the JWT

Comment: To resume: The token generated by the OAUTH system is for the third party. If you want a authentification only for your services, just JWTs  are enough (JWT are nice to be used between trusted services)

Comment: RFC describes OAUTH's process very nicely : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.2
I think you must not use it if your authorization system is just for trusted service, many headache for no gains.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, this i very clear now (but it seems to me that a grant type in oauth corresponds to JWT for first party aplication as well and a previous project I see in company used OAuth for it's own client application managing roles an scopes but it may indeed be too complicated and big for my need, so I'll use JWT)

Comment: You welcome. In addition, OAUTH is an authorization protocol, you probably just need a SSO (then you can hardcode app's rights, it is enough for small apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the front-end should absolutely be authenticating in order to do REST services. Typically using something like OAuth so client can each get a unique token to authenticate with.

If you are saying the server and client are both deployed on an isolated device, my first question would be why you are using that architecture? It *might* be okay to avoid authentication under those circumstances, but you'd really need to spell out the logic behind having a client-server separation in the first place, and consider what attacks are possible.

Comment: OK thank you, isolated device would be a client machine.
And I thought classical way to communicate between angular appli and backend proccessing part was passing through REST ?

Comment: Finally It's not a client-server application but just frontend-backend communicating via REST because I don't know how without REST

Comment: Okay - it sounds like you don't need auth then, if you are just using the web app as an alternative to a native app, and the server is running on the local device too. If the server is running elsewhere, definitely need authentication for any privileged REST requests.

Comment: Okay but others softs on the same device could request the API ? Even if it would be the responsibility of device owner
precision : this is not a totaly isolated device, the backend should requests external DB/API for exemple (but not mines)
But yes  the server will run on each local device

Comment: How should communicate anfular front and back usually otherwise ?

Comment: "Okay but others softs on the same device could request the API ?" Yes. but then they could also access the server's files directly, assuming it's a typical setup, so it's not clear what authentication achieves. (All this depends on a lot of factors, it's hard to say without more info)

Comment: "How should communicate anfular front and back usually otherwise ? " should always be RESTfulwhere possible, the only question is if you authenticate certain calls or not.

Comment: True, Thank you a lot. I won't authenticate for now before refining the needs.
Last question : is it bad to use OAuth for Restful WS ? I already seen that but it is not totally stateless, is this tolerated ?

Comment: It's fine and that's what OAuth is for. Afaik it's essentially stateless in the same sense that a standard web app is stateless using cookies.